# How to write a function that returns ASCII of character without printf in bash

Tags: linux, bash

(Printf "%d\n" \'A) this code is printing the ASCII but I my working with function I want function to return ASCII I am struggling with this .
Please help me.

Comment: why not to use printf? it's a bash bult-in.

Comment: I've got to echo the comment above: `printf` is the right tool for the job. If you're experiencing an issue that makes you think you can't use it, could you let us help you with that issue by describing it in detail? (In a separate question, since this one already has an answer as-asked... but if you ask such a question and want to `@`-notify me there, or link to it from the comments here, I'd be glad to take a look).

Comment: How about `echo A | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t uC`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the POSIX utility `od`:

```
$ echo A | tr -d "\n" | od -An -t uC
           65
```

or `hexdump`:

```
$ echo Z | tr -d "\n" | hexdump -d | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 4
00090
```

Or you could loop through the A-z letters I suppose (no error correction here...):

```
ord() {
    local ordinal=65
    for c in {A..z};
    do
        if [ "$1" = "$c" ]
        then
            break
        fi    
        let ordinal=ordinal+1
    done
    echo "$ordinal"
}

$ ord z
122
```

Or the more 'Bashy':

```
ord() {
    local ordinal=65
    for c in {A..z};
    do
        [[ "$1" == "$c" ]] && break
        (( ordinal++ ))
    done
    echo "$ordinal"
}
```

Bottom line: use `printf`:

```
$ ord() { LC_CTYPE=C printf '%d\n' "'$1"; }
ord A
65
```

Comment: Since you're using `[ ]` rather than `[[ ]]`, should probably use POSIX-compliant `=` rather than the extension `==`.